# Regex works on PCRE, and Python, but not on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex works on PCRE, & Python but not on Javascript.

```
/(?s)\/\*\*\*\/\s\(function\(module,\sexports\)\s\{(.*?)\}\)\,/g
```

It seems that Javascript does not recognize `(?s)`. Is there a Javascript equivalent for this?

https://regex101.com/r/IjWLqp/1

Comment: JavaScript does not support the inline modifier ~ http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall

Answer (score 1):

`(?s)` enables the `s` regex flag for the remainder of the pattern, which means that the `.` matches any character at all, instead of its default behavior of matching any character *except* newline. However, JavaScript, besides not supporting `(?flags)`, doesn't have an `s` flag to begin with. Instead, we can replace the `.` pattern with `[^]` (the negation of an empty character class), which has the same effect of matching any character at all.

The overall pattern is then

```
/\/\*\*\*\/\s\(function\(module,\sexports\)\s\{([^]*?)\}\)\,/g
```

Comment: Makes a a lot of sense.  Thanks for the excellent explanation.  Is there a doc which describes what js can do vs others?